# Right align column in android table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to draw a table in which last column should be at the right most side of the table.

This is how the table row looks like:

```
Admin (2)New
Network (2)New
```

And this is how it should be:

```
Admin (2)         New
Network (2)       New
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center" android:background="@color/list_bg">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>



            <ImageView android:id="@+id/t1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/t2" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t10" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:text=" " android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t4" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true" android:text="("
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t5" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t6" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true" android:text=")"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/t3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t7" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="visible" android:singleLine="true" android:text="New"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this xml t7 should be right at right most side of the table, how to do this???

Comment: You can group LinearLayout and other views to make your TableRow more column-esque. So instead of having a single table row with 8 columns, you would have a single row with two columns (like your example).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here you have to do

1. set the table row width to `fill_parent`
2. and set the `android:layout_gravity="right"` to the textview which you want to align right it to the table row

   ---- or ----

1. add the weight to the textview inside a table row so that they can align how you want.

Comment: This is what I did    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"> and <TextView android:id="@+id/t7" android:typeface="normal"
    android:visibility="visible" android:singleLine="true" android:text="New"
    android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> But it does not work???

Comment: did you get your requirement with first method?

Comment: check out [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/489#) for how to add weight to the table row items

Answer (score 23):

1. **android:stretchColumns="x"** where x is the column you want to fill
2. **android:layout_width="fill_parent"** to ensure everything fills the screen
3. **android:layout_gravity="right"** for the view component in column "x"

example (pseudo code):

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Left Column" />
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:text="Right Adjusted Column" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: The importance of #1 is that typical table layouts are dominated by a column which contains the most data. If that column is two small your table row heights could all be different sizes.